# How to allow X_FRAME_OPTIONS for Facebook in Django app

Tags: python, django, facebook, canvas

in my Django `settings.py` file I have

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ....
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

and

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM https://apps.facebook.com/'
```

This is because I want my app to be displayed in Facebook canvas, but it isn't working as I keep on getting

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email%2Cpublish_actions&state=7…edirect_state%3D7EdHoAcZYlnIaURuz1YI8sbRhxhBg2iM&client_id=420498651348242' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**PD:**

I need framing to use `{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}` **after login into Facebook**

**--> EDIT:**

Explanation of what I need: I want my app to work in Facebook Canvas, after login into Facebook successfully, I need to make a redirection (call the Django auth login url).

When doing this, I get

```
Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email%2Cpublish_actions&state=7…edirect_state%3D7EdHoAcZYlnIaURuz1YI8sbRhxhBg2iM&client_id=420498651348242' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

So I tried channging `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` in my `settings.py', when doing

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

The error changed to say that `X-Frame-Options` was `SAMEORIGIN` instead of `DENY`.

This is why I asked on how I could make X-Frame-Options to allow framing in Facebook, so I could get my app to work in Facebook Canvas.

Sorry for bad explaining. If yet not explained correctly, please ask for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Your `X-Frame-Options` header allows loading *your application* in frames hosted at `apps.facebook.com`, but your problem is that you're loading *the Facebook OAuth dialog* in your frame hosted at your application's domain. You would need a `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM <your-application-url>` *on the Facebook OAuth dialog itself*, which unfortunately cannot be accomplished, as it is up to Facebook and they have explicitly disallowed this arrangement. The Facebook OAuth dialog is intended to open in a pop-up window.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of what can I do?

Comment: Open the FB OAuth dialog in a pop-up window instead of inside an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain myself. The auth dialog is working, as I said, I can get to log in into facebook, but when I get the object with the facebook profile {Object {id: "100002xxx5344", name: "name.surname", first_name: "Name", last_name: "Surname", link: "https://www.facebook.com/name.surname"…}} I want to log in to my own app. That's where it isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: This certainly isn't what your question says. Consider editing your question with more details and a better explanation of your situation.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question explaining better the issue. Hope I've explained well this time. Sometimes it's difficult to explain a problem you are stuck into and have no idea on what to do